# SUBSTRING negative start position

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, select

I need to convert the following statement to use Postgres, but Postgres doesn't allow negative starting positions. Any suggestions?

```
SUBSTR('02', -2, 2)
```

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTR('02', -2, 2) from dual` why is it important to select from dual in this statement, wouldn't you expect to get '02' as a result regardless of the contents of dual?

Comment: Yes, i'd expect to get 02. I just hard coded that for an example.

Comment: @HaleemurAli - it's Oracle, which does not allow bare selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do pattern matching instead. You can get the last two characters of a string like so:

```
substring('02' from '.{2}$')
```

Pattern `'.{2}$'` means: any two characters at the end of the string.

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to take the substring from the right-end, I would suggest using the right function.

```
SELECT RIGHT('02', 2) 
-- outputs 02
```

Comment: I think this is the best equivalence.